# Multiple criteria search query in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to make a complex search on a table with 20 columns.
The user has a form in which he can choose from 0 to 18 criteria to make the search. I capture these criteria in a controller method and return the result to a view. The problem is that I don’t know how to construct the query. I tried with 2 criteria, with the below function, but it doesn’t return a collection, it’s very strange to me what the output of `dd($items`) is. Anyway, the function doesn’t return anything if I remove `dd($items)`, it’s like it doesn’t find anything in the table (which is impossible because I inserted the criteria in such a way that the function should return something).

```
public function looksomething($param1=null,$param2=null){
$query= "all()->";
if($param1!=null)
    $query.="where(’Field1’,’$param1’)"."<br>->";
if($param2!=null)
    $query.="where(’Field2’,’$param2’)"."<br>->";
$query.="get()";
$items=tablename::query();
return view('someview’,['items'=>$items]);
}
```

So, in the above function, you can see how I thought I should buid my search query. It resembles the model I had for classic php. 
First, I don’t know what I’m doing wrong. 
Second, does Laravel have some built-in mechanism that builds complex search query ?

Comment: Do you use Elqoent? Like the models? And Methods like YOURMODEL::all() ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I use.

Answer (score 4):

For simple searching, you could define a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes) method in your model that takes an array of parameters as the second argument, and then adds any clauses you need. Something like this:

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    public function scopeFilter($query, array $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('column')) {
            $query = $query->where('column', '=', $request->get('column'));
        }

        // And so on...

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then you can just pass request parameters from your controller action to your model:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $results = SomeModel::filter($request->all())->paginate();

    return view('some.view', compact('results'));
}
```

Comment: So i guess that the array $request will be populated automatically with the data that comes form the form ? How do I pass the data from the form to SomeModel ?

Comment: @Texas If you look at the second code example, you’ll see the request data is passed to the model via the filter scope.

Comment: @MartinBean how's `scopeFilter` being used in the controller?

Comment: @joshuamabina `SomeModel::filter()`.

Comment: @MartinBean I am finding it hard to understand how `SomeModel::filter` references `SomeModel::scopeFilter`. Please elaborate.

Comment: @joshuamabina https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes “Once the scope has been defined, you may call the scope methods when querying the model. However, you do not need to include the scope prefix when calling the method.”